# I want to order by alternating numbers in MS SQL like 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3 etc

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I have a table in an MS SQL database with a column containing the value 1 or 2 or 3

Now I would like to do an ORDER BY where I get the records like this 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3

This looks harder then it is.. I've been programming for like 10 years and this one got me stuck ;-)

Anyone have any good ideas?

Comment: What year? Why do you want to do this? what other data is involved? How many rows?

Comment: What result would you expect if the table contained 3 rows with 1, 4 rows with 2, and 5 rows with 3? What decides which of the rows with a value of 1 is the first 1, the second 1, etc?

Comment: Without more detail, this general approach is what I would try: union three selects (one for each value 1,2,3) include a rank in each select, and sort the union result by rank followed by value. see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/186133 for the rank part

Answer (score 8):

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(A INT) 

INSERT @T VALUES(1),(1),(1),(2),(2),(2),(3),(3),(3)

SELECT A FROM (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A ORDER BY A) R, A
FROM @T
) B
ORDER BY R, A
```